# Model-theoretic algebraic closure in non-algebraically closed field

Tags: field-theory, first-order-logic, model-theory

It is well-known that if $M$ is an algebraically closed field, then the model-theoretic algebraic closure of any set $A \subset dom(M)$ is the same as its algebraic closure in the sense of field theory (roots of polynomials in $A[x]$). Does the same hold if the field is not algebraically closed? I need a proof or a counterexample.

Comment: What have you tried?

Comment: @MarkKamsma Frankly, I have no idea.

Comment: Maybe I misunderstand the question, but wouldn't any non-algebraically closed field be a counterexample (so concretely e.g. $\mathbb{Q}$)? For a non-algebraically closed field $F$ the model-theoretic algebraic closure of $F \subseteq F$ is just $F$, while the algebraic closure in the field-theoretic sense has to be bigger.

Comment: @MarkKamsma I think the most reasonable interpretation of the question is "for an arbitrary field $F$, does model-theoretic algebraic closure of a subset $A$ agree with the *relative* algebraic closure in $F$ of the subfield generated by $A$?

Comment: @MarkKamsma  The text of the exercise I'm trying to solve is a bit ambiguous, but I agree with Alex's interpretation.

Comment: Why do you "need" a proof or a counterexample? Under my interpretation, this seems a bit too hard for a homework problem, except maybe in a really advanced class in model theory of fields.

Comment: @AlexKruckman It is actually a problem left to the reader in the handouts for a not-so-advanced course on model theory, maybe with the possibility of discussing it during an oral exam.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are certainly fields which are not algebraically closed, but in which model-theoretic algebraic closure agrees with relative field-theoretic algebraic closure. For example, this happens in real closed fields, p-adically closed fields, and pseudofinite fields.

On the other hand, this is not true in all fields. Many examples are given / constructed in the following paper: https://www.jstor.org/stable/3648549